# Gui not updating properly (from async)

Tags: c#, user-interface, asynchronous, delegates

I have a problem that has been driving me crazy all week. I have a really simple asynchronous TCP client/server that I have created. When I receive a TCP message I want to prepend it to a textbox (basically a simple chat program). I realize that the asynchronous methods are run on a background thread so I use `InvokeRequired` to make sure the GUI is updated by the correct thread (see code below).

The messages are received and added to the textbox. The weird thing is that whenever a new message is received the textbox adds the new message, but deletes everything else. This only occurs for the asynchronous calls (other calls don't erase the textbox). Is there any reason for this?

Thanks

```
private void UpdateText(string message)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateDelegate update = new UpdateDelegate(UpdateText);
        this.Invoke(update, new object[] { message });
    }
    else
    {
        textHistory.Text = message + System.Environment.NewLine + textHistory.Text;
        textHistory.Refresh();
    }
}
```

The Write statements were placed to make sure the textbox was being properly accessed by the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private void UpdateText(string message)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateDelegate update = new UpdateDelegate(UpdateText);
        this.Invoke(update, new object[] { message });
    }
    else
    {
        var V = message + System.Environment.NewLine + textHistory.Text;
        textHistory.Text = V;
        textHistory.Refresh();
    }
}
```